# Can anyone please explain why the same code gives different results if written in Python 3 or Ruby?

Tags: ruby, python-3.x

During my ProjectEuler attempt to solve [Problem 23](https://projecteuler.net/problem=23), I found a blog online and prepared the same version of the script in Python 3 and Ruby, just to test which one was faster.

The Python 3 one prints an answer that is the Ruby one's answer - 1141.

I modified the two scripts a little to point out the right value in which the two scripts start to have different behavior.

I can not explain why, though.

This is the Ruby script:

```
def divisors(num)
  divisors = []
  (1...Math.sqrt(num)).each do |x|
    if num % x == 0
      divisors.push x
      temp = num/x
      divisors.push temp if temp != num && temp != x
    end
  end
  return divisors
end

def is_abundant?(num)
  sum = 0
  divisors(num).each {|x| sum += x}
  return sum > num
end

def main(limit)
  numbers = (1..limit).select {|number| is_abundant? number}
  sum = 0
  canbewrittenasabundantsum = []
  canbewrittenasabundantsum[limit]= nil

  numbers.each do |num1|

    numbers.each do |num2|

      if (num1 + num2) <= limit
        canbewrittenasabundantsum[num1+num2] = true
      else
        #break
      end
    end

  end

  (1...limit).each do |num|
    sum += num if canbewrittenasabundantsum[num].nil?
  end

  return sum
end

def prova
  puts("1140 -> #{main(1140)}")
  puts("1141 -> #{main(1141)}")
  puts("1142 -> #{main(1142)}")
  puts("1143 -> #{main(1143)}")
  puts("1144 -> #{main(1144)}")
  puts("1145 -> #{main(1145)}")
  puts("1146 -> #{main(1146)}")
  puts("1147 -> #{main(1147)}")
  puts("1148 -> #{main(1148)}")
  puts("1149 -> #{main(1149)}")
  puts("1150 -> #{main(1150)}")

  puts "#{divisors(1141).inspect}, #{is_abundant?(1141)}"
  puts "#{divisors(1142).inspect}, #{is_abundant?(1142)}"
end


prova
```

This is the Python 3 one:

```
from math import sqrt

def divisors(num):
    divisors = []
    for x in range(1, int(sqrt(num))+1):
        if num % x == 0:
            divisors.append(x)
            temp = num//x
            if (temp != num and temp != x): divisors.append(num/x)
    return divisors

def is_abundant(num):
    return sum(divisors(num)) > num

def main(Limit):
    numbers = [x for x in range(1,Limit + 1) if is_abundant(x)]
    sums = 0
    canbewrittenasabundantsum = [False for x in range(0,Limit+1)]

    for num1 in numbers:
        for num2 in numbers:
            if (num1+num2) <= Limit:
                canbewrittenasabundantsum[num1+num2] = True
            else:
                break

    for num in range(1,Limit):
        if not canbewrittenasabundantsum[num]:
            sums += num
    return sums

def test():
    print("1140 -> {}".format(main(1140)))
    print("1141 -> {}".format(main(1141)))
    print("1142 -> {}".format(main(1142)))
    print("1143 -> {}".format(main(1143)))
    print("1144 -> {}".format(main(1144)))
    print("1145 -> {}".format(main(1145)))
    print("1146 -> {}".format(main(1146)))
    print("1147 -> {}".format(main(1147)))
    print("1148 -> {}".format(main(1148)))
    print("1149 -> {}".format(main(1149)))
    print("1150 -> {}".format(main(1150)))

    print(divisors(1141), is_abundant(1141))
    print(divisors(1142), is_abundant(1142))

test()
```

Can anyone explain me why this happens, please? I'm going mad!

PS. These are the two outputs from the scripts:
Ruby:

```
1140 -> 280223
1141 -> 280223
1142 -> 281364
1143 -> 281364
1144 -> 281364
1145 -> 281364
1146 -> 281364
1147 -> 281364
1148 -> 282511
1149 -> 282511
1150 -> 282511
[1, 7, 163], false
[1, 2, 571], false

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Python:

```
1140 -> 280223
1141 -> 280223
1142 -> 280223
1143 -> 280223
1144 -> 280223
1145 -> 280223
1146 -> 280223
1147 -> 280223
1148 -> 281370
1149 -> 281370
1150 -> 281370
[1, 7, 163.0] False
[1, 2, 571.0] False

Process finished with exit code 0
```

So, starting from 1142, Python seems to be 1141 behind Ruby, and I do not understand why this exact value! You can run these scripts up to 28123, and the ONLY value that gives a different result is this! In the last two lines of the output, you can see the divisors and the "is_abundant" result for 1141 and 1142... They're the same too, in both languages!!

Comment: If your Python code is incorrect, you should ask this as a Python question, not a comparison question.

Comment: If you're voting to close, can you do me a favor and instead keep this open? It's an excellent learning question, and as far as I can tell, the Ruby and Python code both have unexpected errors, and the errors differ. Thank you!

Comment: In this site you people spend most of your time closing a lot of questions, instead of giving help. I've seen lots of them closed for stupid things, despite most users found them interesting... It's so sad...

Answer (score 2):

This is a great question IMHO because it spans languages, and even better the languages are very similar.

To diagnose this, you can do a few things:

1. Step through each program in a debugger and compare the output and variables at each step. If you're not used to a debugger, this is a great time to learn because your question is perfect for it. (Or use print statements if you must :)

   ```
   # Ruby
   def proper_divisors(num)
     ...
     puts "proper divisors: #{num} #{divisors}"  # add this line
     return divisors

   # Python
   def proper_divisors(num):
     ...
     print "proper divisors:", num, divisors  # add this line 
     return divisors
   ```
2. Write unit tests for each method. The unit tests will verify that the inputs and output are what you expect them to be. For example, this unit test will fail on your Ruby code, and that tells you that something is amiss in the method.

   ```
   # Presume your Ruby code file name is "sums.rb",
   # and your test code file name is "sums_test.rb",
   # and both files are saved in the same directory. 
   # Your run the test like this: ruby sums_test.rb 

   require_relative "sums"
   require "minitest/autorun"

   class TestEuler < Minitest::Test
     def test_proper_divisors
       # This is a smoke test: we pick a plausible input
       # that is valuable to our app, and see if it works.
       actual = proper_divisors(400)
       expect = [1, 2, 4, 5, 8, 10, 16, 20, 25, 40, 50, 80, 100, 200] 
       assert_equal expect.sort, actual.sort
     end
   end
   ```
3. Focus in on where the error is cropping up, by refactoring the code to use smaller methods. For example, move the first line of your main method to a new method such as `abundant_numbers`.

   ```
   # Ruby
   def abundant_numbers(limit)
     (1..limit).select {|number| is_abundant? number}
   end

   # Python
   def abundant_numbers(Limit):
     [x for x in range(1,Limit + 1) if is_abundant(x)]
   ```

Update: the Ruby code has a bug in the `divisors` method, and here's sample output:

```
 # Ruby output
 proper divisors: 400 [1, 2, 200, 4, 100, 5, 80, 8, 50, 10, 40, 16, 25]

 # Python output
 proper divisors: 400 [1, 2, 200, 4, 100, 5, 80, 8, 50, 10, 40, 16, 25, 20]
```

Notice the Ruby output is missing the final result of 20.

Your Ruby code bug is this line:

```
 1...Math.sqrt(num)
```

The fix is changing your three dots to two dots:

```
 1..Math.sqrt(num)
```

Ruby syntax says two dots is up-to-inclusive, three dots is up-to-exclusive.

Example:

```
 (1..3).to_a   #=> [1, 2, 3]
 (1...3).to_a  #=> [1, 2]
```

Your existing Ruby code is testing all numbers up to, but not including, the square root.

Comment: Thank you for your time! I already did what you suggested, in a very "manual" way! (I'm not a programmer, I'm a chemist, I just write some code for fun!) In fact, the two scripts are modified to show the point in which they differ! I've added the two outputs in the main question, I think it's a little clearer now! Please have a look of you have time!